# Interactive plots from Quarto docs not rendering inside R Shiny using iframe, How to render Quarto ".qmd" files within R Shiny app?

Tags: html, shiny, r-markdown, quarto

**Goal**
I want to render multiple Quarto files (.qmd) inside existing one R Shiny App

**Current Solution**
My current solution is to render Quarto files into html and disply html files inside R Shiny App, however this does not work for interactive plots. I am aware that I can use shiny inside Quarto documents but I want to render quarto with its functionalities inside R Shiny.

**Reproducible Example Code**

app.R

```r
library(shiny)
library(quarto)

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Reproducable Example"),
                
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    textInput(inputId = "user_argument", label = "Argument"),
                    br(),
                    actionButton("render_button", "Render Quarto ")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(uiOutput("quarto_output"))
                ))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$render_button, {
    quarto::quarto_render("example.qmd",
                          execute_params = list(user_arg = input$user_argument))
    html <-  readLines("qmd_output.html")
    # Display html in output
    output$quarto_output <- renderUI({
      tags$iframe(srcdoc = html,
                  height = "500px",
                  width = "100%")
    })
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

example.qmd

````
---
title: "Quarto HTML Basics"
format:
  html:
    code-tools: true
    self-contained: true
    output-file: "qmd_output.html"
    theme: cosmo
execute:
  warning: false
params:
  user_arg: NA
---



```{r}
#| label: fig-temperatures
#| fig-cap: "New Haven Temperatures"

library(dygraphs)
dygraph(nhtemp) %>% 
  dyRangeSelector(dateWindow = c("1920-01-01", "1960-01-01"))
```

## Argument

My name is `r params$user_arg`.
````

**Observations**

1. The interactive plot is working when quarto renders the html and not working when same html is rendered inside R Shiny
2. I am using iframe because directly inserting the html inside the R Shiny also overrides the css from inserted html.

**Help**

1. Is there any other way to render Quarto files inside R Shiny App?
2. If no, any option to render interactive plots in Shiny from html?

Comment: Similarly how to run a R Shiny App inside another R Shiny App?

Answer (score 1):

## New answer

After juuust a bit of tinkering, I got the iframe to work, and the CSS doesn't spill over. Here's what I did:
First, create a `www` folder in your directory where app.R lives. Web resources can be easily used if they are placed in this directory.
Next, move `example.qmd` inside the www folder. Finally, change the observeEvent to this:

```
observeEvent(input$render_button, {
    quarto::quarto_render("www/example.qmd", #note the www/
                          execute_params = list(user_arg = input$user_argument)
                          )
    html <-  "qmd_output.html" # WITHOUT www! Because www/ is implicit in src calls
    # Display html in output
    output$quarto_output <- renderUI({
      
      tags$iframe(src = html,
                  height = "500px",
                  width = "100%")
    })
  })
```

### Original reply

Not a perfect answer, but this will get your Quarto document showing up:

change the observeEvent to this:

```
observeEvent(input$render_button, {
    quarto::quarto_render("example.qmd",
                          execute_params = list(user_arg = input$user_argument))
    html <-  "qmd_output.html" #CHANGED you defined this name in example.qmd
    # Display html in output
    output$quarto_output <- renderUI({
      # I didn't get iframe to work, but using the next line will load the generated HTML
      includeHTML(html)
  })
```